# Problem with sending files through HttpRequest

Tags: apex, integration, files, httprequest, httppost

I'm getting problems when try to send files larger than 3MB (aproximated) to third-party through HttpRequest in a Integration Apex Class. This third-party tell us than they received the request but with null body, but debugging our code we can see that is sending the base64 encoded file correctly.

Here is a little snippet from the code:

```
HttpRequest httpReq=new HttpRequest();
httpReq.setMethod('POST');
httpReq.setEndpoint(endpointData);
httpReq.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
httpReq.setHeader('cache-control','no-cache');
httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
httpReq.setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding','base64');
httpReq.setTimeout(120000);
httpReq.setHeader('authorization','Bearer '+ERPToken);
httpReq.setBody(JSON.serialize(jsonMAP)); //Se serializa la estructura
System.debug('@@@ Request: ' + httpReq.getBody());
Http http=new Http();
HTTPResponse res=http.send(httpReq);
String responseBody=res.getBody();
system.debug(responseBody); //This returns "Message: Error" if file larger than 3MB
```

At the moment, I haven't got any problems with files smaller than 3MB, and this errors with files larger than 3MB started a few weeks ago. Before that time it works fine with both size-typed files.

It is possible than this could have change because a recent Salesforce release or similar?

Comment: assuming this is a synchronous transaction, you only have 6MB of Heap so every transformation of the payload may increase heap usage - if breached, one would normally get. a limits exception but that's not what the 3rd party observed. Can you delegate to an async transaction with 12 MB heap?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. It's an asynchronous transaction, and the error happens when I try to send, for example, only one file of 5,5MB. This works fine about a few weeks ago, I don't understand why now is failing and with files smaller than 6MB.

Comment: compare your code between now and when it was working to see if you introduced something that would expand Heap - like the last two lines. Use `Limits.getHeapUsage()` for clues